# C++ collision detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sqrt

Alright I need to do a collision test.  This way seemed simplest but my compiler doesn't think so.  Thanks for any replies!

C++ Code:

```
int sqrd(int num) { return (num*num); } //squares a number

bool checkColShip() {
  for(int x = 0;x < 10;x++) {
    double distance = 0; //use to be int tried to change it
    distance = abs( sqrt( sqrd((one.getXPos() - asteroid[x].getXPos()) +
                          sqrd((one.getYPos() - asteroid[x].getYPos()))
                   ); //include cmath
    distance -= 20;//ship radius
    distance -= 20;//asteroid radius
    if (distance<=0) return true;//collision true
  }
  //no collision
  return false;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
c:\documents and settings\all users\documents\c++ projects\learn sdl\learn sdl\main.cpp(702): error C2668: 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(589): could be 'long double sqrt(long double)'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(541): or       'float sqrt(float)'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(127): or       'double sqrt(double)'
while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

P.S. I normally indent my code but first time posting here and it kept giving me problems.

Comment: what is `sqrd` and what getXPos(), getYPos() return?

Comment: There, I indented your code for you.

Comment: Compare the square of the distance instead.

Answer (score 5):

The error is saying that there are three available `sqrt()` functions and there is no obvious choice when passing it an `int`.

You must decide if you want `float` or `double` or `long double` by casting the parameter.

*Unrelated to your question - your code is always passing a real, non-negative number to `sqrt()`, so the square root will always be real and non-negative.  Passing the result to `abs()` is unnecessary.*

Comment: `sqrt` is also unnecessary. They don't want to know the distance, just whether the difference in distance is small enough.

Comment: @PeterWood: Yes!  They could instead square the compared values.

Answer (score 2):

For collisions you don't need to perform the square root. Just make sure the square of the distance is less than the square of the collision distance

```
int square(int value) {
    return value * value;
}

bool collide(Object ship, Object asteroid, int collision_distance) {
    int distance_squared = square(xdiff(ship, asteroid)) +
                           square(ydiff(ship, asteroid));
    return distance_squared < square(collision_distance);
}
```

The actual error you were seeing is because `sqrd` returns an `int` and `sqrt` doesn't take an `int`; there are three different versions for floating point arguments. The compiler didn't know the best choice. Of course the best choice is to avoid the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

sqrt needs "double" or at least a "long". But, sqrd is an int.

Answer (score 0):

sqrt( sqrd((one.getXPos() - asteroid[x].getXPos()) is the issue here, like tugrul already stated.

But do you want to draw the square root of a number you squared seconds before in the first place? Why not just cast the difference to an int and thereby get rid of the comma?

Or wait...this is about Pythagoras, isn't it?
In either case, tugrul is correct. sqrt can only work with long double or double.
So make sqrd return 'double' and the error goes away.